# d3js responsive force layout not working in IE 11

Tags: internet-explorer, svg, d3.js

I am using force layout of d3.js ,I wanted to make force layout to be responsive.

I have used below code:

```
var width = 1110 ,height = 600 ;    
svg = d3.select("#d3_drawing_container").append("svg:svg")
                .attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + width + " " + height )
                .attr("overflow", "hidden")
                .append("g");
```

This works perfectly in Firefox and in chrome,but in Internet explorer (IE Version:11.0.9600.16428) svg element doesn't getting height from the viewbox property.

Comment: so what's your question? any reason you don't simply set the `height` (and `width`) attributes on the `<svg>` element?

Comment: If i add height directly the force layout is not behave as responsive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `height` and `width` directly on the `<svg>` element as well.

```
var width = 1110 ,height = 600 ;    
svg = d3.select("#d3_drawing_container").append("svg:svg")
                .attr("width", width).attr("height", height)
                .attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + width + " " + height )
                .attr("overflow", "hidden")
                .append("g");
```

Comment: But if i use height attribute on svg it is not responsive.

Comment: Actually i have to conditionally add the height specific for internet explorer

Comment: Especially in case of IE We have to set height and width where as in other browser it is ok if we want to retain responsive nature.

Answer (score 0):

Along with the above suggestion you also have to add the below CSS changes. This will set the height and width along with the responsiveness. Hope this helps.
    #svg {
        width: 100%;
    }

Answer (score 0):

But these is not a perfect solution for responsive ness you have to remove height and width from svg container...........
the code like these.

```
var width = 1110 ,height = 600 ;    
svg = d3.select("#d3_drawing_container").append("svg:svg")
                .attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + width + " " + height )
                .attr("overflow", "hidden")
                .append("g");
```